# Make the select box unselected after a selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a niceSelect Plugin

https://github.com/hernansartorio/jquery-nice-select

here is my code, it works good but i want to reset it after i select the option to open it

```
$("#otherlogins").niceSelect();

    $(document).on("change",".socialselection",function() {
        var e = $(this);
        var mode = $('div.nice-select.socialselection span.current').text();
        if(e.val() == '') {
            jAlert('warning', 'Please Choose the Service which you want to use for Login', 'Oops');
        } else {
            WinOpen('openlogin.cfm?mode='+ mode,'page');
            e.attr('data-value') = ''; - This is throwing an error 
        }   
    });
```

Comment: from e.attr('data-value') = '' to e.attr('data-value', ''). refer to [.attr( attributeName, value )](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2)

Comment: ok, Thanks but that does not reset the select to empty, it keeps the selected value as is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to reset the selectyou need to:

- select the first option
- call niceSelect update callback

The snippet:

```js
$("#otherlogins").niceSelect();

$(document).on("change",".socialselection",function() {
    var e = $(this);
    var mode = $('div.nice-select.socialselection span.current').text();
    if(e.val() == '') {
        jAlert('warning', 'Please Choose the Service which you want to use for Login', 'Oops');
    } else {
        //WinOpen('openlogin.cfm?mode='+ mode,'page');
        $("#otherlogins").val($("#otherlogins option:first").val())
        $("#otherlogins").niceSelect('update');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-nice-select/1.1.0/css/nice-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-nice-select/1.1.0/js/jquery.nice-select.min.js"></script>


<select id='otherlogins' class="socialselection">
    <option data-display="Select">Nothing</option>
    <option value="1">Some option</option>
    <option value="2">Another option</option>
    <option value="3" disabled>A disabled option</option>
    <option value="4">Potato</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can destroy and re-initiate plugin as below:

```
$("#otherlogins").niceSelect();

    $(document).on("change",".socialselection",function() {
        var e = $(this);
        var mode = $('div.nice-select.socialselection span.current').text();
        if(e.val() == '') {
            jAlert('warning', 'Please Choose the Service which you want to use for Login', 'Oops');
        } else {
            WinOpen('openlogin.cfm?mode='+ mode,'page');
            $("#otherlogins").niceSelect('destroy');
            $("#otherlogins").niceSelect();
            //e.attr('data-value') = ''; - This is throwing an error 
        }   
    });
```

Hope it helps you.